# How to split among two different characters

Tags: c#, split

I have a string, like this:

```
string x="3*10^5";
```

and I need to split it among the '*' and '^' characters, so that its array form will contain 
`"3", "10", "5"`

So I tried:

```
string x="3*10^5";
List<string> arr;
foreach(char i in x){
    if(x[i].ToString()=="*")/*IndexOutOfRange Exception */{
        arr= ToStringList(x.Split('*'));
    }
    else if(x[i].ToString()=="^"){
        arr=ToStringList(x.Split('^'));
    }
}
```

My function:

```
List<string> ToStringList(string[] arr){
   List<string> w;
   foreach(string i in arr){
       w.Add(i);
   }
   return w;
```

}

But this code is throwing an IndexOutOf Range Exception
How can I make one part of the array split by '*' character and another part by '^' character?

Comment: how about `string[] strs = Regex.Split(x, @"[^\d]");`

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - why use a regex for something so simple?

Comment: @Vadim why assume `*` and `^` are the only tokens he needs to split?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - I don't assume anything, I just dislike regexes. They are very powerful and are great in some scenarios. They are overkill and add too much code complexity in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = "3*10^5".Split("*^".ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
string x = "3*10^5";
string[] result = x.Split(new[] { '*', '^' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.Split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) to split your string on one or more characters that you specify:

```
string x = "3*10^5";

var parts = x.Split('*', '^');
```

The resulting string array contains:

- 3
- 10
- 5

Answer (score 1):

You can use overloaded version of [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var splitted = x.Split(new [] { "*", "^" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** you can use `String.Split()` method to perform splitting using multiple delimeters.

Try This:

```
 string x="3*10^5";
 string [] split = x.Split(new Char[] { '*', '^' });
```

**Solution 2:** if you have any empty string items you need to pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as second argument to `String.Split()` function  to ignore the Split operation on Empty Items.

Try This:

```
 string x="3*10^5";
 string [] split = x.Split(new Char[] { '*', '^' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```